# Why can't I wrap an initialization list in parentheses?

Tags: c, arrays

I would normally declare and initialize an array of integers like so:

```
int a[3] = { 1, 2, 3}; // declares an array of 3 integers
```

But today it occurred to me to wrap the list in parentheses as well, like so:

```
int a[3] = ( { 1, 2, 3} ); // gives compile time error
```

Which produced the following compiler error:

```
expected ';' before '}' token
invalid initializer
```

Naturally, one would normally have no reason to wrap the list in parentheses, but now I'm curious - why *can't* we use parenthesis here?

Comment: You mean besides one is an array initializer and the other is an array initializer containing one other array initializer?

Comment: Can you put the compilation error in your question. I am sure that compiler would have meaningful information about why it does not compile.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg , in `C` the simple parenthesis are generally used to change the precision order and the curly braces for declaring structures.

Comment: The difference is that the second statement is not valid syntax, and so doesn't compile.  (Not sure what else there is to say about it...)

Comment: Statement-2 invalid initializer syntax.

Comment: When I first saw the question it looked like the outer parentheses was curly-braces. Now I see they are parentheses, and the solution is still as obvious as before, but for another reason.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, Yeah it's trivial to get compile time errors if you use wrong grammar.Can you post some link to standards.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Comment: You consider syntax is a joke. Don't you?

Comment: @AyushJain, i think you should understand that when one encounter a error situation while solving a problem; he doesn't need to explain the whole problem for solving the error.The root cause of the problem is enough.Edited my post, have a look.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, asking you a random opinion. Does the quality of my post not sufficient to meet the standards ?

Comment: @black_perl: I'm not a downvoter, but I'd guess that it's because your question is essentially equivalent to "why can't we use £ symbols here?" - the answer is "because the language standard doesn't permit you to".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, i asked it because the use of parenthesis is quite common in a programming language and universal too.Well, thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's simply not valid syntax.  Here are the relevant sections of the grammar from the C99 standard:

**[6.7]**

> ```
> init-declarator:
>     declarator
>     declarator = initializer
> ```

**[6.7.8]**

> ```
> initializer:
>     assignment-expression
>     { initializer-list }
>     { initializer-list , }
> ```

Comment: Yes, finally got what i want.

Answer (score 3):

Your second statement is not valid as per the C language specifications.

You just can't use `()` anywhere deliberately!

As mentioned by Oli Charlesworth on your post,this isn't a valid syntax!

Yeah,as per your thinking now, you are just providing a new way of dealaration,which in real is set as per standards and can't be amended for one's own purpose and as per his own thinking.

So,the standard says you have to use `{}` this only,no extra `()` above or anywhere without standard.It's all upto the syntax defined for each one and accordingly gives compiler errors,if not obeyed!

Comment: Did you mean "everywhere indisciminately"?

Comment: Exactly, it's C syntax you can't change it

Comment: Yeah @Deduplicator. One can't use () anywhere he wishes. He has to be cautious and also refrain from doing so in most of the cases.It in't a calculation of numbers or so!

Comment: Well @black_perl,I'll have to search for a while.Wait I am processing it and will add to my answer!

Comment: "anywhere deliberately" are not the right words. Basically you can use parentheses where such are allowed in the syntax

Comment: Well I think the meaning comes out of it in the same context.I might be wrong though @giorashc.Sorry,but you can edit it if you wish!

Comment: No biggie, the first line tells it all :)

Comment: SORRY your highness,if you feel so,please edit it accordingly.I am not really satisfied,it gives extra importance for OP's deliberate act of using `()` everywhere.Please don't mind but I'm really not getting satisfied!SORRY for not obeying you.

Comment: Wow dude, I did not mean to make you do anything I just made a point about that line in the answer. I even upvoted the answer. No need to be upset, stay cool.